# Add multiple JSIModule React-Native Android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Hi guys I need to plug in multiple JSI Modules into my react-native android app. I tried as below but I am not sure this is the right way:

```
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.ammarahmed.mmkv.RNMMKVJSIModulePackage;
import com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedJSIModulePackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JSIModulePackage;

...

@Override
    protected List<JSIModulePackage> getJSIModulePackage() {
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      packages.add(new RNMMKVJSIModulePackage());
      packages.add(new ReanimatedJSIModulePackage());
      return packages;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the best way:

**change your code:**

```
@Override
protected List<JSIModulePackage> getJSIModulePackage() {
  List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
  packages.add(new RNMMKVJSIModulePackage());
  packages.add(new ReanimatedJSIModulePackage());
  return packages;
}
```

**to this:**

```
return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
       new RNMMKVJSIModulePackage(),
       new ReanimatedJSIModulePackage()
    );
```

Comment: bro, i think you use old way syntax

Answer (score 0):

`react-native-mmkv-storage` gives instructions on how to use both `RNMMKVJSIModulePackage` and `ReanimatedJSIModulePackage` together: https://rnmmkv.vercel.app/#/gettingstarted?id=gt050-installation-steps

> Go to
> node_modules/react-native-mmkv-storage/android/src/java/com/ammarahmed/mmkv
> and copy file named RNMMKVJSIModulePackage.java to Your
> Project/android/app/src/main/java/com/your/project/name/ and paste the
> file there.
>
> Rename the file to CustomMMKVJSIModulePackage.java
>
> Open the file in VSCode and make the following changes:

```
package com.ammarahmed.mmkv; // <-- CHANGE TO YOUR PACKAGE NAME

import com.facebook.react.bridge.JSIModulePackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JSIModuleSpec;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptContextHolder;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedJSIModulePackage; // <-- ADD THIS
import com.ammarahmed.mmkv.RNMMKVModule; // <-- ADD THIS


public class RNMMKVJSIModulePackage implements ReanimatedJSIModulePackage  { // <--- REPLACE RNMMKVJSIModulePackage implements JSIModulePackage with CustomMMKVJSIModulePackage extends ReanimatedJSIModulePackage
    @Override
    public List<JSIModuleSpec> getJSIModules(ReactApplicationContext reactApplicationContext, JavaScriptContextHolder jsContext) {
        reactApplicationContext.getNativeModule(RNMMKVModule.class).installLib(jsContext, reactApplicationContext.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/mmkv");

        return super.getJSIModules(reactApplicationContext, jsContext); // <-- ADD THIS
    }
}
```

> then import this file instead in MainApplication.java as mentioned
> above and make the following changes:

```
import com.your.project.name.CustomMMKVJSIModulePackage; // <- add here
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JSIModulePackage; // <-- ADD THIS
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
          return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }

        // add this method to load our CustomMMKVJSIModulePackage.
          @Override
          protected JSIModulePackage getJSIModulePackage() {
              return new CustomMMKVJSIModulePackage();
          }
        //  
      };
```

Following these steps worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

my bro, what you did is  right

```js
@Override
    protected List<JSIModulePackage> getJSIModulePackage() {
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      packages.add(new RNMMKVJSIModulePackage());
      packages.add(new ReanimatedJSIModulePackage());
      return packages;
    }
```

I use the same syntax in react-native v0.66.3  as you did, and it works well but if you use an old version like v50-v60 maybe
try this

```js
 @Override
            protected List<JSIModulePackage> getJSIModulePackage() {
               return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
           new RNMMKVJSIModulePackage(),
           new ReanimatedJSIModulePackage())
```